# How to prevent requests not coming from my website inside was api gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Please consider the image below.

[image]

I have a website which follows this structure. And I have enabled CORS in my API Gateway to '*'. Even if I restrict the CORS to be my domain name inside API Gateway, I can still make successful Postman requests by copying the `access_token` returned by the Auth0 server.

I am trying to check if the incoming request is generating from my website inside my lambda authorizer.

However, I noticed that the event object for that lambda does not contain the request.headers.origin. I have tried both TOKEN type and REQUEST type authorisers but none of them contain the Origin header.

How can I check/ensure inside my lambda handler that the request is coming from my website?

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

PS:
This website is a very simple website, and due to budget constraints, I don't want to use AWS WAF or other costly services, at least at this moment.

Comment: You can't do that, even if you compare the Origin Postman can just set whatever Origin it wants. What you want is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: Hi @luk2302 thanks for your feedback. If it is impossible, then what would be a way for me to allow incoming requests generated inside my website only, considering the budget constraints?